# TypeError:a.x is undefined

Tags: javascript

I have a array of list like a dictionary

```
CONTORNO = [
{tipo: "m", x:[0,0]},
{tipo: "l", x:[0.06,0],x:[0.06,0.04],x:[0.14,0.04],x:[0.14,0],x:[0.24,0],x:[0.24,0.04],x:[0.34,0.04],x:[0.34,0],
x:[0.44,0],x:[0.44,0.04],x:[0.54,0.04],x:[0.54,0],x:[0.64,0],x:[0.64,0.04],x:[0.74,0.04],x:[0.74,0],x:[0.8,0],
x:[0.8,1],x:[0.40,0.55],x:[0,1]}

 ]
```

and then a function where I call this array

```
function caminho(c,a)
{
   c.beginPath();
   for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++) 
   {
      if(a[i].tipo=== "m")
      {
        c.moveTo(a.x[0],a.x[1]);
    }else if (a[i].tipo === "q") {
        c.quadraticCurveTo(a.x[0],a.x[1],a.x[2],a.x[3]);
    }else if(a[i].tipo === "l") {
        c.lineTo(a.x[0],a.x[1]);
    }
}
c.closePath();
 }


caminho(c,CONTORNO);
```

but I'm getting this error TypeError:a.x undefined.
I'm new in javascript so if you can help me I appreaciate. I'already searched on internet but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: Use a[1].x because a[1] are the item in loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change `c.moveTo(a.x[0],a.x[1]);` to `c.moveTo(a[i].x[0],a[i].x[1]);` and so on for others

```js
function caminho(c, a) {
  c.beginPath();
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].tipo === "m") {
      c.moveTo(a[i].x[0], a[i].x[1]);
    } else if (a[i].tipo === "q") {
      c.quadraticCurveTo(a[i].x[0], a[i].x[1], a[i].x[2], a[i].x[3]);
    } else if (a[i].tipo === "l") {
      c.lineTo(a[i].x[0], a[i].x[1]);
    }
  }
  c.closePath();
}


caminho(c, CONTORNO);
```

Answer (score 0):

a Object must have the property x.

Then when access the object in loop should say "i select 'a' zero" a[0] and access to 'x' property

Example:

```
a[0].x
```